# Use Timer class to call move()

Tags: java, swing, math, timer, imageicon

ok so I created a method that randomly moves an enemy icon, and I used a Swing timer to make it constantly repeat and update every second or so, but the problem is the icon isn't moving it's just staying at the position, I added a print method to display my random numbers, and they are being created and displayed properly, but my enemy is not moving, any help is greatly appreciated :) and the ImageIcon for the bluespell class is a method that jus returns a regular ImageIcon there's nothing wrong with that method ha

```
public class BlueSpell extends WizardBattleGrid{
    private int BlueSpellx;
    private static int BlueSpelly;
    private ImageIcon Blue;
    WizardBattleRunner wbr = new WizardBattleRunner();
    Timer timer;

    public BlueSpell(int x, int y, ImageIcon BlueSpell){
        BlueSpellx = x;
        BlueSpelly = y;
        Blue = BlueSpell;

    }

    public int getx(){

        return BlueSpellx;
    }

    public int gety(){

        return BlueSpelly;
    }

    public ImageIcon getIcon(){

        return Blue;
    }

    public int changex(int x){

        BlueSpellx = x;

        return x;
    }

    public int changey(int y){

        BlueSpelly = y;

        return y;
    }



    public void shootSpell(){
        final BlueSpell b = new BlueSpell(GoodGuy.getx(), GoodGuy.gety() +1, BlueSpellWizard());
        int delay = 60;

            timer = new Timer(delay,new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


                if(b.gety() != 19){
                    WizardCells[b.getx()][b.gety()].setIcon(null);
                    WizardCells[b.getx()][b.changey(b.gety()+1)].setIcon(b.getIcon());

                }

                else{
                    WizardCells[b.getx()][b.gety()].setIcon(null);
                    b.changex(GoodGuy.getx());
                    b.changey(GoodGuy.gety() +1);
                    timer.stop();

                }

            }


        });
            timer.start();







    }










}
```

WizardCells are in my Grid class here they are:

```
public class WizardBattleGrid extends GameWindowWizard {
    public static JLabel[][] WizardCells = new JLabel [20][20];
    public static JPanel WizardPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(20, 20, 0, 0));
    static BufferedImage cursorimage = new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    static Cursor blankcursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(cursorimage, new Point(0, 0), "blank cursor");





        public static void CreateGrid(){

         for(int i=0; i<WizardCells.length; i++ ){
            for(int j=0; j<WizardCells[i].length; j++){

                JLabel label = new JLabel();
                WizardCells[i][j] = label;


            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<WizardCells.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<WizardCells[i].length;j++){


                WizardPanel.add(WizardCells[i][j]);


            }

        }



        WizardCells[10][0].setIcon(GoodGuyWizardIcon());





        WizardPanel.setOpaque(true);
        WizardPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        WizardPanel.setCursor(blankcursor);

        gameWindow.add(WizardPanel);

    }




    }
```

Comment: Could you post your implementation of `getIcon()` and `setIcon()`? Also, you do realize you're changing the x-values for up/down and y-values for left/right? Is that what you wanted it to do? That seems backwards.

Comment: Note that usually x is used for moving left and right and y for up and down. Regarding your problem, my bet is that it is in code not shown. Perhaps you have more than one WizardCells array (which should be renamed wizardCells to comply with Java naming conventions), one displayed, and one being moved. Don't know.

Comment: Ok I just posted all the missing code, and yes I did notice the x and y thing it bugs the hell out of me too, just not enough for me to go in and fix it lol

Comment: I'm not able to see your error yet, but I do see 1) misuse of inheritance and misuse of static variables, two things that you'll eventually want to fix. Regarding your error, you'll want to do more debugging to isolate the problem, including using a debugger. If you fail that, then try to create and post a [minimal, compilable and runnable example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), one that is very small, but runs for us unchanged, that if it uses images uses ones that it downloads from the internet.

Comment: Alright thank you I'll try to go over it, and thanks for the info on inheritance and static variables, if you don't mind can you share with mne what they are, this is my first actual big java program, so sorry for the noob questions haha